# How to set the Unicode of the output of this spider?

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy

I built a spider to scrape a news website and i have to pass the scraped items to the "Clear_html" function to do some edits on the scraped string, but it seems that i have some problems with Unicode:
This is the function:

```
def clear_html(html):
    text = re.sub(r'<(style).*?</\1>(?s)|<[^>]*?>|\n|\t|\r', '', html)
    text = text.encode("utf-8")
    textlist= text.split()
    money=[]
    for word in textlist:
        if re.search('^P', word) and re.search('[0-9]', word[1:]):
            x = textlist.index(word) +1 
            y = str(word)+" " +textlist[x]
            money.append(y)
   delete=[]
   for word in textlist:
        if word.startswith("("):
             if word[1].isupper() and word[2].isupper():
                 delete.append(str(word))
             else:
                 pass
   for word in textlist:
       if word == "Image" and textlist[textlist.index(word)+1] == "courtesy":
             imageindex= textlist.index(word)
             dl= textlist[imageindex:]
             for d in dl:
                 delete.append(str(d))

    replacements ={}
    for item in delete:
         replacements[str(item)]=''
    for item in money:
        eitem = item.replace("P","")
        eitem = eitem.split()
        if re.search('^billion', eitem[1]):
            replacements[str(item)]= eitem[0]+" billion"+" Phillippine peso"
        elif re.search('^million', eitem[1]):
            replacements[str(item)]= eitem[0]+" million"+" Phillippine peso"
        else:
            replacements[str(item)]= eitem[0]+" Phillippine peso"
    def multireplace(s, replacements):
        substrs = sorted(replacements, key=len, reverse=True)
        regexp = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, substrs)))
        return regexp.sub(lambda match: replacements[match.group(0)],s)
    text = multireplace(text, replacements)
    return text
```

And this is the output:

> Port operator International Container Terminal Services, Inc.  through
>   its wholly-owned subsidiary, ICTSI Oregon, Inc., and the Port of
>   Portland have agreed to terminate in March a 25-year lease agreement
>   to operate the container facility at the Port\u2019s Terminal 6.

I do not need anything like this "\u2019" which appears on the last line i need it to be port's terminal 6.
can anyone help?

Comment: Try with `text.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')`

Comment: @ZdaR that isn't necessary. The output is correct, that is the unicode representation of `’`. Try `print text` and you will see that your output is correct. What's exactly the problem with your output containing unicode characters?

Comment: @eLRuLL i do not need it to contain any thing except the natural words because it will go through a program to read it and convert it to an audio clips.
so i do not need anything like this \u2019

Comment: @ZdaR it did not solve the problems. it still produce \u2019!

Comment: have you already tried passing that string to your other program? (not copy-pasting of course)

Comment: @eLRuLL till now i make that process manually copy and paste. i need to automate the process and that's why i wrote this piece of code into my spider.

Comment: continue with your project, leave that string as it is, it won't give your problems.